# NHibernate query latest N per group

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have the following domain mapped through FluentNHibernate

```
class Point
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

class PointData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public DateTime Hour { get; set; } 
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime Available { get; set; } // Data arrival (data tracking)
}
```

The PointData table will update frequently inserting new values (updates not supported) for an Hour, but not all points write PointData at the same frequency.

I need to get the latest PointData per Point for all hours between startTime and endTime and before timeOfSnapshot(available).

My query so far using Linq to Nhibernate using group by does not work:

```
Query.Where(x => x.Available <= available && x.Hour >= startHour && x.Hour < endHour)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Available)
                    .GroupBy(x => new {x.Location, x.Hour})
                    .Select(g => g.First())
                    .ToList();
```

All searches so far only came up with SQL queries, which is not exactly what I want.

Help is appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the group by result with the original rows and return the rows:

```
rows.Join(
   rows.GroupBy(x => new {x.Location, x.Hour}), 
   x => new {x.Location, x.Hour, x.Available}, 
   g => new {g.Key.Location, g.Key.Hour, Available = g.Max(p=>p.Available)},
   (x1,g1) => x1
)
```

Put a profiler on and you will see this sql:

```
SELECT [t0].*
FROM [rows] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX([t1].[Available]) AS [value], [t1].[Location], [t1].[Hour]
    FROM [rows] AS [t1]
    GROUP BY [t1].[Location], [t1].[Hour]) 
AS [t2] ON (
    [t0].[Location] = [t2].[Location]) 
    AND ([t0].[Hour] = [t2].[Hour]) 
    AND ([t0].[Available] = [t2].[value]
)
```

Comment: This is correct, but ran into a problem which I did not expose in the question. The domain was simplified for various reasons, but in the running application we use DateTimeOffset, and not DateTime. NHibernate throws an exception that DateTimeOffset is not supported as Identifiers in group by clauses. According to the NHibernate roadmap, this is fixed in the coming version 3.3.3. So untill that one arrives I use two round trips to the database.

Answer (score 0):

After a group by, you cannot extract more columns than are used in the grouping key, or aggregates. If I understand your question correctly, the usual pattern for this is to use a subquery that will pick the identifiers of the interesting rows, then an outer query to get all the columns for those rows. Try something like this:

```
var latestPointId =
    Query.Where(x => x.Available <= available && x.Hour >= startHour && x.Hour < endHour)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Available)
        .GroupBy(x => new {x.Location, x.Hour})
        .Select(g => g.Max(pd => pd.Id));

session.Query<PointData>
    .Where(pd => latestPointId.Contains(pd.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You are right about the group by and extraction of columns. Tried your example, but it did not quite work. Also in your example you assume that the max Id is the same as latest available, which won't be the case if you reseed the table identifier.

Comment: You're correct about the id. The true key of the grouped rows is {Location,Hour,Available}, which should be selected from the subquery and then used to find the complete matching row. This, however, requires putting the subquery in the FROM clause of the resulting SQL. Unfortunately NHibernate is unable to generate this. Maybe you need to look for a hybrid solution involving for instance a named SQL query.

Comment: Thx I will look at a hybrid solution, but my luck using both fluent nhibernate and xml config is not good so far. Currently I actually use 2 queries, one which gets all data filtered (Query with Where clause), then I use Linq to Objects to create the Group By query in memory. It works, but it's not performant in the long run.

Comment: If you use two queries, one option is to first materialize my first query above (getting location, hour and available). Then use a second query to get the complete PointData instances. Use PredicateBuilder (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to form a large OR-condition over data from the first query. The second query might be heavier for the DB, so this depends on how rows you expected to get from the first query.

Comment: Btw, it's strang that you've had problems combining Fluent with XML mapping - I've never experienced it.